# Which sorting algorithm is this?

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I was trying to implement bubble sort in python, but turns out it's not bubble sort, it's faster than bubble sort. Can somebody please enlighten on me what sorting algorithm I implemented?

```
def not_bubble_sort(data, n):
   for i in range(n):
       for j in range(i+1, n):
           #swap
           if data[i] > data[j]:
               temp = data[i]
               data[i] =  data[j]
               data[j] = temp
```

Comment: It kinda looks like a selection sort with extra swapping: at the end of each $j$-loop, the index $i$ will contain the smallest element among indices $i$, …, $n - 1$.

Comment: you are right. it performs much worse than selection sort